# Keeping track of doc's words count in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm writing a [Google Docs Add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/) and would like to keep track of word count in the extension whenever user adds/deletes new word.

My initial approach is:

in **Code.gs**:

```
function getWordCount() {
  var st = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getText().replace(/\n/g, ' ') + ' ';
    st = st.split(/\s* \s*/).length;
    return st - 1;
}
```

in **Sidebar.html**:

```
var docCount = 0;
function updateWordCount(data) {
   if(data) {
     docCount = data;
   }
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateWordCount).getWordCount();
}
```

But it seems very 90th... is there any way to push data from google apps script to client side? I know about Google Realtime API but it doesn't work in apps script for Google Docs.

Regards

Comment: Do you mean a Google Doc Add-on or a Chrome extension for to use with Google Docs?

Comment: @Jacobvdb Google Doc Add-on

Comment: About the feedback look at this [example](https://github.com/google/google-apps-script-samples/tree/master/cursor_inspector)

Comment: @Jacobvdb okay your example has exactly the same approach.